# How do I exclude specific numbers from a Regex expression?

Tags: regex

I have the following regex expression.

```
[1-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]
```

It matches numbers between 10.00 to 99.99 in increments of.01 (e.g., 11.00 or 11.44, or 65.90).

Let's say I have two numbers that I would like to be excluded from this range. 13.00 and 44.51.

How would I add this condition to the expression?

Twist: I'm using Google Forms to validate this and it doesn't recognize negative look-aheads (!?...)

Does anyone know how I would go about solving this?

Answer (score 3):

Negative lookaheads are fine for this job but unfortunately not all regex engines support them. So a workaround is to do a positive match and discard instead.

Eg

```
(?:13\.00|44\.51)|([1-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9])
```

Accept only if group `1` is matched else discard (this means the wrong numbers were matched instead)

PS: The answer assumes one can test which part of the regex matched and discard if not group `1` is matched. It is not supposed to work without additional programming logic, only negative lookaheads could achieve that.

Comment: I [used this regex](https://imgur.com/a/dBmL024) but it seems to accept 13 and 44.51.

Here is my form: https://forms.gle/N65b9RD58QHbpS6p7

Comment: The answer assumes one can test which part of the regex matched and discard if not group 1 is matched. it is not supposed to work without additional programming logic, only negative lookaheads could achieve that

Comment: Ah okay, I guess that's the limitation of using Google forms. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, you can technically still do it without negative lookahead if you're willing to manually make the regex longer, something like `([235-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]|1[0-24-9]\.[0-9][0-9]|13\.[1-9][0-9]|13\.0[1-9]|4[0-35-9]\.[0-9][0-9]|44\.[0-46-9][0-9]|44\.5[02-9])`

Comment: @justhalf, correct one can explicitly list only valid values and make a really long regex out of that, but may not be practical or sometimes not even possible

Comment: Very clever +1.  Missed the part about no lookaheads.